# How to increase the server startup timeout in WSO2 Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I want to make an oracle database connection by opening a dataservice project with WSO2 Integration studio application. I can connect to the Oracle database. But when I run the dataservice project, the WSO2 Integration Studio application goes into time out and asks us to increase the time out time. How and where should we increase this time?

Integration Studio Dataservice project Xml :

```
   <data transports="http https" serviceGroup="" serviceNamespace="" name="demoDataService">
  <description />
  <resource method="GET" path="GetGenders">
    <call-query href="GetGenders" />
  </resource>
  <config id="OracleDataSourceIdenfierName" enableOData="true">
    <property name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/schema_name</property>
    <property name="username">username</property>
    <property name="password">password</property>
  </config>
  <query id="GetGenders" useConfig="OracleDataSourceIdenfierName">
    <sql>SELECT column1,column2 FROM schema_name.table_name</sql>
    <result outputType="json">{
"Genders": {
    "Gender": [
      {
        "column1": "$column1",
        "column2": "$column2"
      }
    ]
  }
}</result>
    <properties>
      <property name="fetchDirection">forward</property>
    </properties>
  </query>
</data>
```

WSO2 Integration Studio Timeout Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Show View -> Other` Then search for Servers. Select Servers and click on Open.

[image]

Then Double Click on the "Micro Integrator Server 4.1" Then look for the timeout settings.

[image]

Comment: I opened a dataservice project in Integration Studio. I have provided Oracle database connection using OData. I added a select query that fetches records from one table. Then it takes a long time to run this dataservice project and get it up and running. I think it scans all the tables in the database. As a result it works but takes minutes. Why could this be and how can I solve it?